# API Platform POST requests don't send JSON data when using Groups

Tags: symfony, http, post, api-platform.com

I have a problem : all my POST requests don't send the JSON data attached when i use Groups in my Symfony's entities. When they're don't here all works but i need to use these Groups. Anyone knwo what is wrong an how to fix it ?
Thanks :)

EDIT:
I use this code as normalizationContext

```
@ApiResource(
 *     formats={"json"},
 *     forceEager=false,
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"subscriber:read"}, "enable_max_depth"=true},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"subscriber:write"}, "enable_max_depth"=true})
```

And in my fields i have the line

```
@Groups({"subscriber:read"})
```

But my groups are working for all GET requests it's only for POST where the json data is empty :(

(Sorry for my bad english i'm in learning ^^)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you configured it a bit wrong, check the [documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/v2.5/core/serialization/)

So in your example it should be smth like:

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(attributes={
 *     "normalization_context"={"groups"={"subscriber:read"}},
 *     "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"subscriber:write"}}
 * })
 */
```

Comment: No my entity is good all works, i found the issue : because i don't need denormalization groups remove this line has solved my problem, it was weird but it works ^^ The official documentation dont explain those problems it just explain how it work i've already read it :)